# Quartz.NET inject property in a job

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I use Quartz.NET this way:

```
ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

scheduler.Start();

IJobDetail clearCacheJob = JobBuilder.Create<ClearCacheJob>()
                        .WithIdentity("ClearCacheJob", "CacheGroup")
                        .Build();
scheduler.ScheduleJob(clearCacheJob, buildTrigger(cacheCronExpr));
```

`ClearCacheJob` is a class that implements `IJob`

It works, but now I want to add a property in the `ClearCacheJob` class. Something like:

```
public class ClearCacheJob : IJob
{
    public ISomeService {get; set;}
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

How can I set `SomeService`?

Comment: You'll need either a custom `IJobFactory`, or if you are using a DI container, one which has an extension library which sets all that up for you. Ninject and StructureMap come to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stuart's comment is spot on. You'll need to implement your own job factory. I've written a blog post describing the process here: http://jayvilalta.com/blog//2012/07/23/creating-a-custom-quartz-net-jobfactory/

As far as DI containers goes, Castle is also supported. Do a [search on NuGet for Quartz.Net](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=quartz.net) and scroll through the list. You'll see castle, structuremap, ninject, autofac, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but I have also written a blog post with a full working example using Ninject. The blog post can be found here:

<strike>http://codein60seconds.blogspot.com/2015/08/quartz-with-ninject-dependency-injection.html</strike>

The source code for the example can be found here:

<strike>https://github.com/cknightdevelopment/CodeIn60Seconds/tree/master/DotNet/QuartzWithNinject</strike>

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

Blog post is now here:

http://knightcodes.com/.net/2016/08/15/dependency-injection-for-quartz-net.html

And the source code here:

https://github.com/cknightdevelopment/KnightCodesExamples/tree/master/DotNet/Quartz.Ninject

And the YouTube video here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlW4vUsoxEY

Comment: "Blog has been removed".